# Are part numbers on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It's easier to locate parts if you have the manufacturer's part number, especially discontinued parts.  I know of only two ways to get my hands on part numbers, enthusiast sites and dealer parts departments.  I've never been able to find a part number by searching by make / model and description, even if I'm using the correct nomenclature.

***Update***

Here's the sort of thing I had in mind:

[Broken window crank handle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/broken-window-crank-handle)

[Broken washer hose junction and clip hardware](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/broken-washer-hose-junction-and-clip-hardware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked two questions (with very helpful answers) that were effectively part number queries so I vote **YES**:

[What bolt is a replacement for the front sway bar bolts on a 2004 Subaru WRX wagon?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/199/what-bolt-is-a-replacement-for-the-front-sway-bar-bolts-on-a-2004-subaru-wrx-wag)

[Which of these two front struts is the correct one for a 2002 Subaru Outback?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/which-of-these-two-front-struts-is-the-correct-one-for-a-2002-subaru-outback)

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with Bob, although IMHO they are better if they are in the form of "How do I find the right part number for a doohickey on a Mk5 Ford Thingymabob" rather than "What is the part number for this particular part that I need" - i.e. More like Bob's second question than his first.

Comment: Yes, but it then leads to the old 'give a man a fish' problem - tellin someone one part number doesn't help them next time they need a number for a different part. Telling them how to find the right part number does...

Comment: Nick's answer is totally fair and I think the site supports that sort of constructive criticism: he (or somebody else) could comment on the question and suggest an edit.